# Check if item to geocode begins with a number in Python

Tags: python, geocoding

I'm reading addresses from a csv to geocode them. Currently my Python script checks if the address contains a number with this (I only want to geocode addresses that begin with a number, e.g. "81 St Nowhere street, New York"):

```
if hasNumbers(item) == True:
```

However, this means an address of the form "81 St Nowhere street, New York" would work AND so would "The Silly Boat, Pier 6, New York".

I only want addresses that start with a number in the first position to be geocoded (i.e. ignore the Pier 6 type addresses, and only geocode addresses that start with a number).

What's the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test if the first character is a number.

```
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

for item in items:
  if is_number(item[0]):
    #Do stuff
```

In Python3 you can just use:

```
for item in items:
  if item[0].isnumeric():
    #Do stuff
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use regex then

```
import re
pattern = r"^\d.*"
if re.match(patten, word):
    print "Match Found"
```

Pattern:

`^` - asserts position at start of the string

`\d` -  matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

`.*` - Matches any character expect "\n" any number of times.